# how to find the distinct values of a field in a MongoDB collection using Node MongoClient

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my MEAN application, I need to find the distinct values of a field named "DataFields" from my collection "Fixed_Asset_Register", using (non-mangoose) MongoClient:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var assert = require('assert');

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);

        var collection = db.collection('Fixed_Asset_Register');
        var distictDataFieldsValue = ?

}
```

What is the proper syntax to get back the distinct values of the field named "DataFields"?

Comment: Are you looking for [db.collection.distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) ?

Comment: Let's say, I have a 100 documents in a given collection. Each document has a field named "DataFields". The value of this field varies from one document to another. I need to have a list of distinct values for this field across all documents

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue using [collection.distinct](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#distinct):

```
collection.distinct("DataFields",(function(err, docs){
            console.log(docs);
            assert.equal(null, err);
            db.close();
        }))
```

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept your answer as soon as you can !

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this by way of **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**. The suitable aggregation pipeline would consist of the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator stage which groups the document by the `DataFields` key and create an aggregated field `count` which stores the documents produced by this grouping. The accumulator operator for this is [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum).

The next pipeline stage would be the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator which then filters the documents having a `count` of 1 to depict distinction.

The last pipeline operator [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) then group those distinct elements and adds them to a list by way of [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push) operator.

In the end your aggregation would look like this:

```
var collection = db.collection('Fixed_Asset_Register'),
    pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$DataFields",
            "count": {"$sum": 1}
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": { "count": 1 }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "distinct": { "$push": "$_id" } 
        }
    }],
    result = collection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray(),
    distictDataFieldsValue = result[0].distinct;
```

Comment: Is this approach better then just using db.collection.distinct?

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg `db.collection.distinct` is better as [it will use the index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/#index-use) if available.